# I can not remove blender

Tags: 14.04, command-line, uninstall, blender

I want to install the new version of blender (2.75), but first I have to remove my old version of blender (2.74), I try to remove blender with this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove blender
```

but when I type this in the terminal, the terminal says this:

```
Package 'blender' is not installed, so not removed
```

although terminal says this I can open blender.

Comment: How did you install blender? The correct package name is blender. Therefore I believe, not with apt, or?

Comment: My old version of blender, I think that I installed from the blender page, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: If that is the case, just remove the extracted folder it, should be something like `blender-2.74-linux-glibc211`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [installation](https://www.blender.org/download/) instructions, simply remove you blender folder.

1. Find the folder with

   ```
   find ~ -type d -iname "*blender*"
   ```

   or if there is no result

   ```
   find / -type d -iname "*blender*"
   ```
2. Remove the blender folder

   ```
   sudo rm -r <your_installation_folder>
   ```

---

*Example*

```
% find ~ -type d -iname "*blender*"
/home/aboettger/tmp/blender-2.75-linux-glibc211-x86_64
/home/aboettger/tmp/blender-2.75-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.75/scripts/addons/io_export_dxf/draw_blenders
```

Therefore

```
% rm -r /home/aboettger/tmp/blender-2.75-linux-glibc211-x86_64
```

Comment: The terminal says"Permission denied"

Comment: sorry, with `sudo`

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: You've found the directory and then it is suddenly no longer there?

Comment: Post the output of your find command in your question.

Answer (score 0):

there is a folder in your home its a hidden folder in my case I had a plug in that went bad and would try to load it no matter what. so in my case it was 
ps4/home/.config I just deleted that folder after uninstalling and all is good now.